# The control with ID 'SomeControlId' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it (but it does)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, master-pages, scriptmanager

ASP.NET AJAX scriptmanager problem:

I get a Yellow Screen of Death with:

> The control with ID 'SomeControlId' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

BUT - there **is a scriptmanager on the page**, and it **does work on the dev box** (the error appears only on the live production server).

I've already tried:

- removing the scriptmanager,
- putting it (just) in the master page,
- putting a proxy scriptmanager in (with the scriptmanager also in the master page),

...but no luck.

Any other ideas? Will posting code help?

**Update:**
I installed ASP.NET 3.5 (and restarted, shortly before asking this question) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Does your production server have the AJAX Extensions for 2.0 or ASP.NET 3.5 installed?

Comment: I installed ASP.NET 3.5 (and restarted, shortly before asking this question) but it didn't help.